# Why there is no need to restart server when any changes in controller in newer version of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for answer, why we need to restart server in older version of rails during any change in controller and why we don't need in newer version of rails.

Comment: in which version you need to restart server ?

Comment: What versions are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

By default all autoloaded paths are tracked for changes by the rails `file_watcher`.
This reloads the class that was changed when a file change is detected, so you don't have to restart the server to reload all classes. I don't know that previous versions didn't have this.
It can be found in `config.file_watcher`.

Rails can also be configured to reload classes for every request using this config option:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change
```

bypassing the file watcher but presumably degrading performance.